# moving or deleting cells caused an invalid cell reference Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Today I have a problem with my excel spreadsheet. I am getting cells displaying #REF! error on the result cell! I checked the formula and there is nothing with it at all.I need to select a calculation from text box and a value from a second text box to give me a value from a table based on my formula! My formula is as follows:

=IF(F55="Select Size","",VLOOKUP(F55,INDRECT(CONCATENATE($F$51,"s")),3,FALSE))

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter in VLOOKUP is a table_array, i.e. a 2-dimensional area in in your spreadsheet defined by the top left corner and bottom right corner, so in your spreadsheet it could be something like $G$1:$I$10.

So for your formula to work using INDIRECT and CONCATENATE, $F$51 would have to contain the first part of a range e.g. the text "$G$1". Then you would need to concatenate this with the second part of the range e.g. ":$I$10" to get a valid range like "$G$1:$I10" as a string which INDIRECT would return as a valid reference like $G$1:$I$10.

But in the formula that you've currently got, whatever is in $F$51 is concatenated with the character "s". I don't know what's in $F$51, but it could only return a valid reference if it's something like "Q:" and you're specifying three whole columns - anything else would give a "#REF!" error.

To see what's happening, go to Formulas | Evaluate Formula.